# Toad of Oracle - create private temporary tables

Tags: oracle, temp-tables, toad

Trying to create private temp table but keep getting error msg, [Error] Execution (1: 16): ORA-00905: missing keyword

The word TEMPORARY is underline in red and when I hover over it is says Found 'TEMPORARY' Expecting: 'OUTLINE' what does this mean and is this causing the error?

```
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ora$ptt_orders AS
(
 select * from orders 
 where rownum < 10
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE DEFINITION;
```

Comment: What Oracle version are you using?

Comment: Toad for Oracle?  v.11.6.0.43

Comment: Private Temporary Tables are available only in Oracle 18c. You are way behind yet using 11g.

Comment: Ok, thanks is there any way I can create temp tables for a session only in version 11.6?

Comment: Do you mix version of TOAD and Oracle version? Oracle version 11.6.0.43 does not exist. Try `select * from v$version;`

Comment: @user15676 not the Toad version, the Oracle database version.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a *private* temporary table in your database version (as you've been told).

But, you can create a *global* temporary table instead. Using *as select*, syntax is like in this example:

```
SQL> create global temporary table ptt_orders
  2  on commit preserve rows
  3  as
  4  select * from emp
  5  where deptno < 50;

Table created.

SQL>
```

You can choose what to do with rows upon commit - to preserve them, or to delete them. Difference is whether table contents is available to you during session or transaction.